# Segmentation fault while reading content from file

Tags: c

I am reading all files in a directory. Following is my code:

```
DIR* FD;
    struct dirent* in_file;
    FILE *common_file;
    char *c;
    FILE *entry_file;
    char buffer[1024];
    if (NULL == (FD = opendir("/home/fatima/Downloads/thesis/HMP_Dataset/Climb_stairs"))){fprintf(stderr, "Error : Failed to open directory \n"); return 1; }
    while((in_file = readdir(FD)))
    {
            if(!strcmp (in_file -> d_name, ".") ) continue;
        if(!strcmp (in_file -> d_name, "..")) continue;
        entry_file = fopen(in_file -> d_name , "r");
        if (entry_file == NULL) fprintf ( stderr, “Error %s”, strerror(errno);
        while (c=fgets (buffer, 1024, entry_file)!=NULL){}

                //printf("%s", c);
}
```

Segmentation fault occurs at innermost while loop while reading content from file. I haven't post stacktrace since only segmentation fault is printed.

Comment: You're not checking what fopen returned in the inner loop.

Comment: ..which is probably failing because the file name does not have the path prepended to it.

Comment: Also, a compound expression:c= 'a=b!=d' means 'c' gets a boolean resuilt.

Comment: ..and then this '//printf("%s", c);' tries to print it like a NUL-terminated char array, (if uncommented).

Comment: @Mat I removed it. It was giving segmentation fault as well.

Comment: Then you were not checking properly. Re-introduce that test, and inspect errno after it.

Comment: @MartinJames I just prepended path to in_file->d_name. Still same segmentation fault

Comment: @Mat just edited

Comment: Flush the output, or add a '\n' to the error print, else a subsequent segfault may prevent any line-buffered output from getting printed.

Comment: @MartinJames added null terminator, cleared the screen, also commented out while loop. Problem persists.

Comment: That can't be the source that you run, as it has a syntax error. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Even prepending gives segfault

Answer (score 0):

It raised seg fault because in_file -> d_name only had filename. Path also needs to be prepended to it. Once full filename with path was given, problem resolved